# Whats the most efficient way to update a partial after an AJAX form submit in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, partial

I have a page with code as follows:

```
<div>
<%= render 'form' %>
</div>

<div id="item_container">
<%= render @item %>  
</div>
```

where form is a form for "@item" and "render @item"  renders a partial that represents "@item". The form uses remote: :true and submits using AJAX.

Whats the simplest and most efficient way in rails 3 to update the entire @item partial when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller action you need to add a respond_to block

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

and you can write a view where you directly write javascript code in it (given your action name is 'update')

**update.js.erb**

```
$('#item_container').html('<%= j render(@item) %>');
```

Note the 'j' that escape for JS response

Comment: I've seen many complex solutions for this elsewhere. But this was simple and perfect. thanks

Comment: more info: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery this is a 2008 rails cast, but will point you to the right direction

Comment: Is this still the best way to achieve this effect? I use this pattern all over my app but wonder if I should be using something like Stimulus instead. What do you think?

Comment: Yep. Still valid ;)